# How to fix 404 error in pagination in categories of woocommerce with common url base /shop/?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, 404-error

I can’t find a solution — unification of url bases of products and categories in woocommerce.

I have found only one working solution:

In Settings -> Permalinks:
Category base change on **shop**
Custom Structure change on **/shop/%product_cat%/**

and add to functions.php code:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'change_requerst_vars_for_product_cat' );
add_filter( 'term_link', 'term_link_filter', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpp_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpp_change_request' );

function change_requerst_vars_for_product_cat($vars) {

    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! empty( $vars[ 'pagename' ] ) || ! empty( $vars[ 'category_name' ] ) || ! empty( $vars[ 'name' ] ) || ! empty( $vars[ 'attachment' ] ) ) {
      $slug   = ! empty( $vars[ 'pagename' ] ) ? $vars[ 'pagename' ] : ( ! empty( $vars[ 'name' ] ) ? $vars[ 'name' ] : ( ! empty( $vars[ 'category_name' ] ) ? $vars[ 'category_name' ] : $vars[ 'attachment' ] ) );
      $exists = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT t.term_id FROM $wpdb->terms t LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat' AND t.slug = %s", array( $slug ) ) );
      if ( $exists ) {
        $old_vars = $vars;
        $vars     = array( 'product_cat' => $slug );
        if ( ! empty( $old_vars[ 'paged' ] ) || ! empty( $old_vars[ 'page' ] ) ) {
          $vars[ 'paged' ] = ! empty( $old_vars[ 'paged' ] ) ? $old_vars[ 'paged' ] : $old_vars[ 'page' ];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $old_vars[ 'orderby' ] ) ) {
          $vars[ 'orderby' ] = $old_vars[ 'orderby' ];
        }
        if ( ! empty( $old_vars[ 'order' ] ) ) {
          $vars[ 'order' ] = $old_vars[ 'order' ];
        }
      }
    }

    return $vars;

  }

function term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {

    $url = str_replace( "/product-category/", "/shop/", $url );
    return $url;

  }

function wpp_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $name ) {

    if ( 'product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;

  }

function wpp_change_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query[ 'page' ] ) ) {
      return;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $query->query[ 'name' ] ) ) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'product', 'page' ) );
    }

}
```

After that all work good, but pagination doesn’t work.

It works only on pages of subcategories https://dverinevada.ru/shop/vhodnye-dveri/kondor/page/2/
But on pages of categories there is 404 error https://dverinevada.ru/shop/vhodnye-dveri/page/2/

We can add such code in functions.php to fix 404 error:

```
function codernote_request($query_string ) {
if ( isset( $query_string['page'] ) ) {
if ( ''!=$query_string['page'] ) {
if ( isset( $query_string['name'] ) ) {
unset( $query_string['name'] ); }
}
}
return $query_string;
}
add_filter('request', 'codernote_request');
```

After that pagination pages doesn’t have 404 error, but there are no products (instead of them message «No products matching your request were found.»).

I ask for help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but on a custom archive-product.php page which contains a custom query to get my products with only 10 results per page.

I had 404 pages on shop page and categories page with the second page of pagination.

After analysis, I found that the main query of WooCommerce asks for 16 results but I had only 12 products in my database. So the main query returns nothing.

To change that, I need to do in admin : Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Catalog and change the value to 1 for Products per row and Rows per page.

With that the main query returns always 1 result and I had no more 404 pages.

I hope that will help you or another.

Source : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-displayed-per-page/